# Data varying in GridView in Android App

Tags: android, gridview

I am developing an Android app which displays information of different historical places. In my App, I have made a page to review and rate the place. The app is retrieving usernames, ratings, and comments from database and displaying it in a GridView. It is displaying correct number of comments but instead of displaying all the comments it duplicates some of the comments. Here is my code which retrieve data from database.

Can anyone tell what is the problem with my code??

```
class task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
{
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Comments.this);
    InputStream is = null ;
    String result = "";
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        if (get)
            progressDialog.setMessage("Retrieving reviews...");
        else
            progressDialog.setMessage("Posting review...");

       progressDialog.show();
       progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() 
       {
           @Override
           public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) 
           {
               task.this.cancel(true);
           }
       });
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

        try 
        {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            //read content
            is =  httpEntity.getContent();  
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        try 
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
               sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
            return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) 
    {
        try 
        {
            if(get)
            {
                name=new ArrayList<String>();
                comment=new ArrayList<String>();
                rating=new ArrayList<Float>();
                JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);

                for(int i=0;i<Jarray.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject Jasonobject = new JSONObject();
                    Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String names=null;
                    names=Jasonobject.getString("name");

                    name.add(names);
                    comment.add(Jasonobject.getString("comment"));
                    rating.add((float)Jasonobject.getDouble("rating"));
                }
                CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(Comments.this, name,comment,rating);                        
                grid.setAdapter(adapter);

                get=false;
            }
        progressDialog.dismiss();               
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter Code:

```
    public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter

    {
        private Context mContext;
        private final ArrayList<String> name;
        private final ArrayList<String>  comment;
        private final ArrayList<Float> rating; 

        public CustomGrid(Context c,ArrayList<String>  name, ArrayList<String>  comment, ArrayList<Float> rating ) 
        {
            mContext = c;
            this.name= name;
            this.comment =  comment;
            this.rating=rating;
        }


    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return comment.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid, null);
            TextView textName = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_name);
            TextView textComment = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_comment);
            RatingBar ratingBar1 = (RatingBar)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_rating);
            textName.setText(name.get(position));
            textComment.setText(comment.get(position));
            ratingBar1.setRating(rating.get(position));
        } 
        else 
        {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }
            return grid;
        }
}
```

Comment: we need your adapter code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`convertView` is null just once. After you inflate and return it, due to the recycling mechanism of the `GridView`/`ListView` it will be never null *again*. What you are doing is assign to your `TextView`s the content of your dataset at position 0, and then return on of the pooled view with the same content over and over. Change your `getView` like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid, null);    
    } 
    TextView textName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_name);
    TextView textComment = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_comment);
    RatingBar ratingBar1 = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_rating);
    textName.setText(name.get(position));
    textComment.setText(comment.get(position));
    ratingBar1.setRating(rating.get(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

also you probably want to look in the [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) pattern, which makes your GridView/ListView scroll smoother